# Implications of independence among random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, conditional-expectation, independence

Consider the real-valued random variables $X,Y,Z,W,A$.

Suppose that $Z,W,A$ are mutually independent and that $Y:=g(Z,W)$ for some Borel measurable function $g:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Assume that $X$ has the same distribution as $Y$.

Does this imply that

**(1)** The distribution of $X$ conditional on $W$ is equivalent to the distribution of $g(Z,W)$ conditional on $W$? 
Could you give some explanations on why yes or why no and whether the independence of $Z$ from $W$ is used?

**(2)** The distribution of $X$ conditional on $(W,A)$ is equivalent to the distribution of $g(Z,W)$ conditional on $(W,A)$? Could you give some explanations on why yes or why no and whether the independence of $A$ from $(Z,W)$ is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assertions (1) and (2) need not be true given your assumptions. The reason is that knowing only that $X$ has the same distribution as $Y$ says nothing about the joint distribution of $X$ with $(Z,W,A)$.

An example where (1) and (2) are false: Say $Z$, $W$, $A$ are mutually independent coin tosses, each taking value $0$ or $1$ with equal probability. Let $Y:= Z+W$, and let $X$ have the same distribution as $Y$ (so $X$ has Binomial($n=2,p=1/2$) distribution), but independent of $(Z,W,A)$. Then $$P(X=0\mid W=1) = P(X=0)=\textstyle\frac14$$ while $$P(Y=0\mid W=1)=P(Z+W=0\mid W=1)=0.$$  Similarly $P(X=0\mid W=1, A=1)=\frac14$ while $P(Y=0\mid W=1, A=1)=0$. The independence of $Z$ from $W$, or the independence of $A$ from $(Z,W)$ doesn't come into play.

Comment: Thanks a lot. May I ask you a further clarification? Since $X$ is distributed as $Y$, sampling from the distribution of $X$ is equivalent to sampling from the distribution of $Y$. Assuming that $g$ is known and that the distribution $f_{Z,W}$ of $(Z,W)$ is known, we can draw a realisation $(z,w)$ of $(Z,W)$ from $f_{Z,W}$ and then set $x=g(z,w)$. Is this procedure correct? Doesn't this mean assuming that $X|W=w$ is distributed as $g(Z,W)|W=w$?

Comment: @STF Until you specify the joint distribution of $X, W, Z, A$ you don't really know how $X\mid W$ behaves.  If you set $X:=Y$ (which is one way to specify the joint distribution) then for sure $X\mid W=w$ is distributed as $g(Z,W)\mid W=w$.

Comment: Are you saying that the sampling procedure above assumes $X\equiv Y$?

Comment: @STF Yes, because your procedure is explicitly generating $y$ from $z$ and $w$, and then setting $x=y$. Knowing that $X$ is distributed like $Y$ doesn't mean that $x$ has to be generated from the same $z$ and $w$ that generated $y$. See the binomial example, where we generate $x$ from a pair of $z$ and $w$ that are *independent* from $y$.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks. I don't know if you are familiar with the Aldous-Hoover representation theorem for graphs, but my question is actually related to that. The theorem just states that if  a random graph $X$ is exchangeable then $X_{ij}\sim 1\{U_{ij}\leq W(U_i, U_j)\}$ $\forall i,j \in \mathbb{N}^2$ where the $U$'s inside are i.i.d. uniforms on $[0,1]$ and $W$ is a random function from $[0,1]^2$ to $[0,1]$. Then many sources conclude that $X_{ij}|W,U_i, U_j\sim Be(W(U_i, U_j))$ which by your answer is not true unless we assume that $(X_{ij},W,U_i, U_j)\sim 1\{U_{ij}\leq W(U_i, U_j)\}$.

Comment: @STF I'm not familiar with this theorem but if I understand the notation then it's fair to conclude that $1\{ U_{ij}\le W(U_i, U_j)\}$ conditional on $W, U_i, U_j$ has the advertised distribution. It's likely that these sources are treating  $X_{ij}$ as if it's identical to $1\{ U_{ij}\le W(U_i, U_j)\}$, and have moved everything to the space where $U_{ij}, U_i, U_j, W$ are living.

Comment: Could I ask you one last thing: without assuming anything about the joint probability of $X, Z, W, A$, suppose I draw a large number of realisations $(z,w)$ of $(Z,W)$ from their joint probability $f_{Z,W}$ and then save all the resulting $g(z,w)$. Then I plot the empirical probability distribution. Is it true that this empirical probability distribution should be close to the probability distribution of $X$?

Comment: @STF Yes, since $X$ has the same distribution as $g(Z,W)$. Exactly what 'close' means is up to debate but this result is just saying that the histogram for a random sample will approximate the population density as the sample size increases.